# Tikzcd. How to align on left?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

I need to align the output on the left instead to be centered. Someone can help?

Code:

```
\begin{tikzcd}[arrows = dash, row sep = 0.5cm]
F[\,x\,]
\arrow[d]
\\
F_n[\,x\,] =  f \in \F[\,x\,] \td  deg \ f <n 
\arrow[d,"n+1"]
\\
F 
\end{tikzcd}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: More precisely, do you want that the arrows point to and from `F_n[x]`?

Comment: you should provide mwe and not only code snippet!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you want something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\F}{\mathbb{F}}
\newcommand{\td}{:}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[arrows = dash, row sep = 0.5cm,column sep=-0.8em]
\F[x]
\arrow[d]
\\
\F_n[x] 
\arrow[d,"n+1"]
& {} = \{ f \in \F[x] \td  \deg f < n \}
\\
\F 
\end{tikzcd} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ThankYou! But this is a trick. There is no a direct solution in the tikzcd options?

Comment: @AndreaLeo Perhaps. I'll look into it. How many situations like this one do you find in?

Comment: I will have a lot of situation like this because my exam of Algebra is full of that diagrams. If you find the solution I will be so glad!

Comment: @AndreaLeo I think you have to resort to methods like in section 3.3 of the `tikz-cd` manual.